Eclipse version 24-6 isn't working with the lombok plugin
I used the lombok.jar installer for eclipse, it modified my eclipse.ini file
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.800.v20240513-1750.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.1000.v20240507-1834
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.3.v20240426- 
   1530/jre/bin
-vmargs
-javaagent:C:/Users/me/eclipse/2024-03/lombok.jar
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclientjava
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=21
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Declipse.e4.inject.javax.warning=false
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Djava.security.manager=allow

every lombok class is failing to compile  because eclipse doesn't know about builders, or getters or setters or constructors
I have the lombok.jar in my eclipse base directory.
I run eclipse by double clicking on the eclipse.exe
Here is the simplest example class
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ClientAccount {

    @Size(max = 30)
    private String accountName;

    @Size(max = 50)
    private String accountReference;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 32)
    private String clientId;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 64)
    private String clientSecretKey;

    private LocalDateTime keyLastUpdated;
}



If I run maven on the command line it generates the correct code (I used a decompiler to see this)
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import lombok.Generated;

public class ClientAccount {
   @Size(
      max = 30
   )
   private String accountName;
   @Size(
      max = 50
   )
   private String accountReference;
   @NotNull
   @Size(
      max = 32
   )
   private String clientId;
   @NotNull
   @Size(
      max = 64
   )
   private String clientSecretKey;
   private LocalDateTime keyLastUpdated;

   @Generated
   public static com.pancredit.equifax.model.ClientAccount.ClientAccountBuilder builder() {
      return new com.pancredit.equifax.model.ClientAccount.ClientAccountBuilder();
   }

   @Generated
   public ClientAccount(final String accountName, final String accountReference, final String clientId, final String clientSecretKey, final LocalDateTime keyLastUpdated) {
      this.accountName = accountName;
      this.accountReference = accountReference;
      this.clientId = clientId;
      this.clientSecretKey = clientSecretKey;
      this.keyLastUpdated = keyLastUpdated;
   }

   @Generated
   public String getAccountName() {
      return this.accountName;
   }

   @Generated
   public String getAccountReference() {
      return this.accountReference;
   }

   @Generated
   public String getClientId() {
      return this.clientId;
   }

   @Generated
   public String getClientSecretKey() {
      return this.clientSecretKey;
   }

   @Generated
   public LocalDateTime getKeyLastUpdated() {
      return this.keyLastUpdated;
   }

   @Generated
   public void setAccountName(final String accountName) {
      this.accountName = accountName;
   }

   @Generated
   public void setAccountReference(final String accountReference) {
      this.accountReference = accountReference;
   }

   @Generated
   public void setClientId(final String clientId) {
      this.clientId = clientId;
   }

   @Generated
   public void setClientSecretKey(final String clientSecretKey) {
      this.clientSecretKey = clientSecretKey;
   }

   @Generated
   public void setKeyLastUpdated(final LocalDateTime keyLastUpdated) {
      this.keyLastUpdated = keyLastUpdated;
   }

I have annotations turned on in the project

but where ever it is used I get the compilation errors
The method getClientId() is undefined for the type ClientAccount        line 43 Java Problem
or
The method builder() is undefined for the type ClientAccount    line 12 Java Problem
Edit I have just updated to lombok version  1.18.34, and it is now appearing, in the about box, but I am still getting errors, anywhere that is trying to use these generated methods

Which version of Lombok are you using? Sometimes newer versions of eclipse are not fully compatible with latest versions of lombok. So try downgrading lombok to a previous version. Also open a ticket on Lombok github page: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues

the latest version 1.18.4, and will do, can I copy and paste this lot?

You have this backwards--it's Lombok that's not fully compatible with Eclipse because Lombok is the one you're injecting in to the JVM.

@nitind you are correct, thanks!

Lombok 1.18.4 has been released October 30th, 2018. For Eclipse 2024-06 Lombok 1.18.34 is needed which has been released four days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78664042/6505250

This has solved the outline and about box problem, but nothing is still compiling

Did you do Project > Clean...?

I'm using eclipse 2024-06 with lombok 1.18.32 and everything works.  Did you install lombok via running the lombok jar or in a different way?

The current release of lombok is v1.18.34. You should install it; we fixed a few things that sound sufficiently like what you're running into.
If you've done that and you still see the errors, make sure you run a project clean all. Or close and re-open all projects.

also my java version somewhere in eclipse I couldn't find was set to java 17
